# navigation bar using flexbox disappears

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to code a project that is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But when I used unordered list and list tags in my html code, the navigation bar (green bar) disappears.

```
    <div class="container">
       <ul class="zone green">
           <li>Head</li>
           <li>Products</li>
           <li>Our Team</li>
           <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>

       <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
       <div class="zone blue">Project Grid</div>
       <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
    </div>
```

and my output becomes this:

[image]

But when I use div tags instead, the navigation bar (green bar) reappears.

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="zone green">
           <div>Head</div>
           <div>Products</div>
           <div>Our Team</div>
           <div>Contact</div>
       </div>

       <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
       <div class="zone blue">Project Grid</div>
       <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
    </div>
```

and my output is this:

[image]

Here is my css code:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: 50px 300px 300px 50px;
   grid-template-areas: "head"
                        "covers"
                        "projectGrid"
                        "footer";    
}

.zone {
   cursor:pointer;
   color:#FFF;
   font-size:2em;
}

.green {
   background: #56B870; 

   display: flex;
   grid-area: head;
}

.red {
   background: #C655BE; 
   grid-area: covers;
}

.blue {
   background: #7abcff; 
   grid-area: projectGrid; 
}

.yellow {
   background: #F3AAAA; 
   grid-area: footer;
}
```

So I'm wondering why this is happening? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ul has some default css becuase of which the green content is not visible

Trying adding this

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none!important;
        margin-block-start: 0!important;
        margin-block-end: 0!important;
        margin-inline-start: 0!important;
        margin-inline-end: 0!important;
        padding-inline-start: 0px!important;
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none!important;
    margin-block-start: 0!important;
    margin-block-end: 0!important;
    margin-inline-start: 0!important;
    margin-inline-end: 0!important;
    padding-inline-start: 0px!important;
}



.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: 50px 300px 300px 50px;
   grid-template-areas: "head"
                        "covers"
                        "projectGrid"
                        "footer";    
}

.zone {
   cursor:pointer;
   color:#FFF;
   font-size:2em;
}

.green {
   background: #56B870; 

   display: flex;
   grid-area: head;
}

.red {
   background: #C655BE; 
   grid-area: covers;
}

.blue {
   background: #7abcff; 
   grid-area: projectGrid; 
}

.yellow {
   background: #F3AAAA; 
   grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <ul class="zone green">
           <li>Head</li>
           <li>Products</li>
           <li>Our Team</li>
           <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>

       <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
       <div class="zone blue">Project Grid</div>
       <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
    </div>
```